# "Log in" and "sign up" to the right or left of the search bar?

Tags: website-design, search, login, best-practice

I wonder if the "Log in" and "sign up" you should put on the right or left of the search bar ...

I am realizing the utility but are not convinced of their position:

[image]

The problem is purely aesthetic

I read three books on 'UXD and I know that the utility must go right and positioned in this order ...

but looking at it as if it is not nice to see ....

perhaps because the bar utility is too long
or perhaps because the words "log in" and "sign up" stops are situated immediately under the "Maps" ....?

So for that I would try to move "log in" and "sign up" to the right of the search bar ....

But guides UXD what they say about it?

What do you recommend?

I had thought of three solutions, but do not know what the right one according to UXD:

1) leave everything just as it is now

2) decrease the width of the search bar (and only when you click to search for something, the width will increase as it is now). In this way, "log in" and "sign up" will be slightly to the right and immediately below the text of the header.

3) move "log in" and "sign up" in the upper right side of the header

Sorry for my english and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this will have a major impact. Anyhow, I'd ask the questions:

- "Is the search more important than the log in?" - if yes, search first.
- "Is the search connected to the login?" - if no, do not group the items, currently you are visually connecting the search and the signup. It creates a connection it might not have and lead to seconds of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context and your users, and at this stage it appears that you can't really tell which they prefer, or how if affects their experience since you're not talking about the results of research that you've done with users.

I would suggest going to [usabilityhub.com](http://usabilityhub.com) and putting it in front of people to see which gets a better response, but bear in mind that the placement actually does have a UX impact beyond the aesthetics; look up [Fitts's Law](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/book/the-glossary-of-human-computer-interaction/fitts-s-law) and it will explain how the infinite canvas of a screen edge makes it much easier to select an object on the screen edge or next to the screen edge (get to the edge, stop, travel a short distance back). There may not be much between selection ease of the log in vs search in this instance, but there is some, and presumably the search function is more important than the log in (in this instance).

Comment: thank a lot! I didn't know fitt's law and usabilityhub ! ;)

Comment: I created a test, if you help me do it: https://usabilityhub.com/do/33891eb89e1d/8da8

Comment: Just an FYI; it looks like you've uploaded the same image (at least insofar as the placement of the login compared to the search bar) for both options.